# Hello Analytics API: Javascript quickstart for web applications

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to create a simple browser application which should work with Google Analytics API. I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js) guide. and I've already created the credentials according to the tutorial and change the **Client ID** in the code, which is also provided on the tutorial page.

The problem is that nothing happens when I run it, no console logs / errors and no output.

Any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong? It's frustrating and real showstopper for me.

This is just a very beginning, just want to run something so I can add code for reading Account IDs from GA (in txt file) and printing all the users with permissions for a give n account.

**EDIT:**

So, this is my code (which is copied from the tutorial page mentioned before):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello Analytics - A quickstart guide for JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="auth-button" >Authorize</button>

<h1>Hello Analytics</h1>

<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

<script>

  // Replace with your client ID from the developer console.
  var CLIENT_ID = "657325877092-e7116fhp5mbqvj970ju00humdtlve6ua.apps.googleusercontent.com";

  // Set authorized scope.
  var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];


  function authorize(event) {
    // Handles the authorization flow.
    // `immediate` should be false when invoked from the button click.
    var useImmdiate = event ? false : true;
    var authData = {
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      immediate: useImmdiate
    };

    gapi.auth.authorize(authData, function(response) {
      var authButton = document.getElementById('auth-button');
      if (response.error) {
        authButton.hidden = false;
      }
      else {
        authButton.hidden = true;
        queryAccounts();
      }
    });
  }


function queryAccounts() {
  // Load the Google Analytics client library.
  gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function() {

    // Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
    gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list().then(handleAccounts);
  });
}


function handleAccounts(response) {
  // Handles the response from the accounts list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {
    // Get the first Google Analytics account.
    var firstAccountId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query for properties.
    queryProperties(firstAccountId);
  } else {
    console.log('No accounts found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryProperties(accountId) {
  // Get a list of all the properties for the account.
  gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list(
      {'accountId': accountId})
    .then(handleProperties)
    .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}


function handleProperties(response) {
  // Handles the response from the webproperties list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {

    // Get the first Google Analytics account
    var firstAccountId = response.result.items[0].accountId;

    // Get the first property ID
    var firstPropertyId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query for Views (Profiles).
    queryProfiles(firstAccountId, firstPropertyId);
  } else {
    console.log('No properties found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryProfiles(accountId, propertyId) {
  // Get a list of all Views (Profiles) for the first property
  // of the first Account.
  gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list({
      'accountId': accountId,
      'webPropertyId': propertyId
  })
  .then(handleProfiles)
  .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}


function handleProfiles(response) {
  // Handles the response from the profiles list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {
    // Get the first View (Profile) ID.
    var firstProfileId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query the Core Reporting API.
    queryCoreReportingApi(firstProfileId);
  } else {
    console.log('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
  // Query the Core Reporting API for the number sessions for
  // the past seven days.
  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions'
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  })
  .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}

  // Add an event listener to the 'auth-button'.
  document.getElementById('auth-button').addEventListener('click', authorize);
</script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to deploy it, have you? It won't work on your localhost

Comment: @MatanBobi Yes I know I need to deploy it (it used to throw error message in console). I've already tried it on free webhosting (https://www.000webhost.com) and on localhost server.

Comment: And what do you get when you try to deploy it? Have you reported any action? page view? can you show your code? have you looked in google analytics to see if any data is in there?

Comment: @MatanBobi I've updated my question so you can see the code. It is the very same code as on the tutorial page + client ID inserted. 

I have no response in chrome console.

Comment: Do you have profiles in your GA? You're asking for them but im not sure you have them...

Comment: @MatanBobi Right in the example I've created something like testing acc for this, so I can post here the Client ID. Otherwise I'm using Client ID for the account with access to 200+ different Accounts/Properties/Views